# Eliminate permutations from table

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is this SQL problem which I've been trying to solve, but I haven't
been able to solve thus far:

Suppose I have a table:

Sequences(number1 int, number2 int, number3 int, number4 int, number5 int)

If there exists a row in Sequences such as:
<1,3,4,2,5>
then I would like to eliminate every other row that is a permutation of this one,
for example the row:
<1,2,5,4,3>.

Edit:
The primary key is (number1, number2, number3, number4, number5)

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: Is there a primary key on that table that would allow you to uniquely identify a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that the values cannot be repeated within the five columns and that the table has a single column primary_key -

```
DELETE t2
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2
    ON (t1.col1 IN (t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3, t2.col4, t2.col5)
        AND t1.col2 IN (t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3, t2.col4, t2.col5)
        AND t1.col3 IN (t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3, t2.col4, t2.col5)
        AND t1.col4 IN (t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3, t2.col4, t2.col5)
        AND t1.col5 IN (t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3, t2.col4, t2.col5)
    )
    AND t1.primary_key < t2.primary_key
    -- AND CONCAT(t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t1.col4, t1.col5) < CONCAT(t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3, t2.col4, t2.col5)
WHERE t1.col1 NOT IN (t1.col2, t1.col3, t1.col4, t1.col5)
AND t1.col2 NOT IN (t1.col3, t1.col4, t1.col5)
AND t1.col3 NOT IN (t1.col4, t1.col5)
AND t1.col4 <> t1.col5
```

I have not tried this so I would suggest running it as a SELECT before committing to the DELETE.

**UPDATE** The following query will work for the case where there are repeated values within the set (1,1,2,2,2 as opposed to 1,2,3,4,5) but the join is very expensive so I would be very cautious when running it against a very large dataset.

```
DELETE t2
FROM `table` t1
INNER JOIN `table` t2
    ON (    t1.col1 IN (t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3, t2.col4, t2.col5)
        AND t1.col2 IN (t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3, t2.col4, t2.col5)
        AND t1.col3 IN (t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3, t2.col4, t2.col5)
        AND t1.col4 IN (t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3, t2.col4, t2.col5)
        AND t1.col5 IN (t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3, t2.col4, t2.col5)
    )
    AND (-- compare the number of occurrences of each value in each side
            (IF(t1.col1=t1.col1, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col1=t1.col2, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col1=t1.col3, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col1=t1.col4, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col1=t1.col5, 1, 0)) = (IF(t1.col1=t2.col1, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col1=t2.col2, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col1=t2.col3, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col1=t2.col4, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col1=t2.col5, 1, 0))
        AND (IF(t1.col2=t1.col1, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col2=t1.col2, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col2=t1.col3, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col2=t1.col4, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col2=t1.col5, 1, 0)) = (IF(t1.col2=t2.col1, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col2=t2.col2, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col2=t2.col3, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col2=t2.col4, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col2=t2.col5, 1, 0))
        AND (IF(t1.col3=t1.col1, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col3=t1.col2, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col3=t1.col3, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col3=t1.col4, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col3=t1.col5, 1, 0)) = (IF(t1.col3=t2.col1, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col3=t2.col2, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col3=t2.col3, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col3=t2.col4, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col3=t2.col5, 1, 0))
        AND (IF(t1.col4=t1.col1, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col4=t1.col2, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col4=t1.col3, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col4=t1.col4, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col4=t1.col5, 1, 0)) = (IF(t1.col4=t2.col1, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col4=t2.col2, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col4=t2.col3, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col4=t2.col4, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col4=t2.col5, 1, 0))
        AND (IF(t1.col5=t1.col1, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col5=t1.col2, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col5=t1.col3, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col5=t1.col4, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col5=t1.col5, 1, 0)) = (IF(t1.col5=t2.col1, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col5=t2.col2, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col5=t2.col3, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col5=t2.col4, 1, 0)+IF(t1.col5=t2.col5, 1, 0))
    )
    AND t1.primary_key < t2.primary_key
    -- AND CONCAT(t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t1.col4, t1.col5) < CONCAT(t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3, t2.col4, t2.col5)
```

If you do not have a single column primary key for the table you can use the commented out comparison instead of the PK one but the PK is definitely preferred.

Comment: The assumption that values can't be repeated within the five columns is a big one, though. If (1,2,3,4,5) is in the table, this could delete many rows from table 1 that are not permutations of 1,2,3,4,5, such as (1,1,1,1,1) or (3,2,3,2,3).

Comment: I have added a where clause to make sure it will only pick up combinations without repeated values. Also added alternative rank comparison (very expensive) for the join in case single column PK does not exist.